# Simulating Sql Server GO statement with EXEC

Tags: sql-server

I have code that given a SQL with the GO statements transforms it to a single SQL statement without the `GO` statements by using the following logic:

```
"EXEC('" + sql.Replace("'", "''").Replace("GO", "');EXEC('") + "')"
```

Of course, the actual logic a bit more robust, but the spirit is the same.

However, `GO` is not equivalent to `EXEC`. For example, the following code works:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp
SELECT 1 A INTO #tmp
GO
SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

And returns:

[image]

However, the version with EXEC does not work:

```
EXEC('
IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#tmp'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp
SELECT 1 A INTO #tmp
');EXEC('
SELECT * FROM #tmp
')
```

The result is:

[image]

Is there a way to eliminate the GO statements so that the resulting SQL can be run in ADO.NET with one SQL command?

**EDIT 1**

I apologize, if my post is confusing for some. I am not looking for ways to create table UDTs or temporary tables.

I am using ADO.NET to talk to a Sql Server database. Specifically, I am using the `SqlCommand` class to run a SQL on the server. If that SQL contains the `GO` statement, then it is an invalid Sql, because `GO` is not a Sql keyword, it is used to delimit batches when ran in the SSMS. So, there are two ways to deal with it:

1. Split the SQL using the GO keyword as a delimited and run each chunk separately. So, if there are N batches, then there will be N `SqlCommand` API calls to run the respective batches.
2. Replace `GO` with `EXEC` as I have described. In this case, there is only one `SqlCommand`, but `EXEC` and `GO` are not equivalent.

So, I am asking if there is another way to respect the `GO` statement in ADO.NET while issuing just one `SqlCommand` API call to the Sql Server.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because you have moved your temp table into dynamic sql. As such it falls out of scope as soon as the dynamic sql completes and the temp table will be dropped. From the code you posted you could just remove GO and run both pieces in the same batch with no issue.

Comment: Well, #tmp  doesn't exist in that second statement because it isn't declared in that batch (connection). GO simply breaks statements into batches in SSMS. You can change the qualifier from GO to anything you want in the settings. Just combine those exec statements....

Comment: Guys, I do not need help to write these SQLs. My goal is to understand whether I can simulate GO in SQL using a single Ado.Net command. I am trying to simulate it with EXEC, but it is not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - NO. If a script is written as multiple batches, then you **must** execute them as multiple batches. You cannot "simulate" the effect of batch separation within one batch execution without changing the tsql used drastically - and that would involve writing to code to interpret and then rewrite the script.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic query will not store the temp table in the temp database therefore you don't need to drop it.

IN SSMS

Try this and should give you what you want.

```
EXEC('SELECT 1 A INTO #tmp;
    SELECT * FROM #tmp');
```

But I think you are leaning towards the use of user-defined table types 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx

where it uses in-memory table that does not consume space and need not to be dropped.

Comment: I know I can do it. The point of the post is to understand if it is possible to simulate the GO statement in SQL using a single ADO.NET command.

Comment: Please, see my **EDIT 1**.